# Why can't types be declared inside functions in F#?

Tags: types, f#

I was reading [this guide to types in F#](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/overview-of-types-in-fsharp/). It says that:

> Types cannot be declared inside functions.

And gives some example code:

```
let f x = 
    type A = int * int  //unexpected keyword "type"
    x * x
```

It seems that if the type were only used *inside* the function (i.e. not returned) then there should not be a problem.

Is there a reason that this is not possible?

Comment: I think its more why would you want to do this?

Comment: Seconding what @JohnPalmer said. I'm having trouble coming up with a *practical* scenario (note the qualifier) where this would be useful. Has this been a problem in practice for you?

Comment: Of course there's a reason. There's a cost to implementing features. This feature is nearly worthless. Why would you waste the time implementing this feature instead of using it on something worthwhile? Do you have a scenario where defining a function-scoped type would be useful?

Comment: @Luaan - I have such a scenario. Other functions may be created within the function and these functions may have arguments of a complex type, like list<int*string>->list<string*float>. Sometimes F# forces one to be explicit about types or one may want to make them explicit to increase code readability. In such cases having an alias for the type would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reasons to have types nested inside functions tend to be outside the capabilities of the F# type system or an indicator of a code style problem.

## The Question's Case: Simple Abstraction

Let's begin with the case in the question, where the type is just some general abstraction or shorthand. There seems to be no demand for this feature in F# – which isn't too surprising. For nesting such a type into a function to be a good idea, the following requirements must be met:

- The values passed around inside a function are confusing enough to need their own type.
- This type is not useful anywhere else and shouldn't be exposed
- The clutter this type would cause, even as a private type in the enclosing namespace or module, is a bigger problem than mixing the type definition into the function.

For this topic to be *relevant*, it gets even weirder:

- This type of issue happens so often that even workarounds like extra modules for internals are not solving it without notable overhead.

Ugh... this sounds like separation of concerns went down the drain before this problem occurs. If there is a case where it's reasonable to create this kind of code, I can't quite figure it out right now. Good code is usually built from small, reusable abstractions. The above sounds like anything but that.

## The Futuristic Case: First-Class Types

There is a much more interesting aspect to this question, which I hope will come back to us in the future. Maybe we want to declare a type inside a function because its definition depends on the function's inputs! What if functions would treat type parameters like any other parameter and let you operate on them?

Such a feature would be a superset of generics and type providers. I imagine it could be a very elegant and very powerful feature. But I don't know of any language that both allows this and has IDE-supported type safety that could compete with F#.

So the answer to that is: types are not first-class values in F#. You'd need a notably different language for this, and such a language doesn't seem to exist yet.

Comment: @sdgfsdh There is a [language called F*](https://www.fstar-lang.org/) which is similar to F# and has dependent types. Though I think this is a largely orthogonal feature to first-class types. Dependent types are concerned with the ability to express additional constraints in types. First-class types would be concerned with the ability to create types in a more flexible fashion, competing with features like C++ templates, code generators, type providers, etc.